# shake sensor in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which involves shaking sensor in android emulator.I have implemented functionality and 4 screens.Now I am facing problem how to implement shake listener in android.Can anybody tell me in advance.Regards Tushar

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the motion sensor. Here is a good tutorial that describes how to do that:

http://www.clingmarks.com/?p=25

Answer (score 0):

Few weeks ago I had the same question as you and first thing I did was google 
"android shake listener" and found several nice tutorials. [This one](http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-shake-detection-listener) might be what you're looking for, isn't it?